# R - Read a SPECIFIC, Single NUMERIC column in CSV file as a string

Tags: r, csv

Let's say I have a data file

```
A    B    C    D
12   34   Yo   67
28   34   Hi   99
```

And I want the CSV file to be read in, so column D is treated as a STRING.  How do I do this?

This is important because I have my column "D" in my real data storing a number like

664607437458295829402840

and it puts it into scientific notation/rounded when I read it in.  I want it treated as a string.

Can I do that?

Comment: You try by specifying `colClasses=` i.e `read.csv('yourfile.csv', colClasses=c(rep(c('numeric'), 2), 'character', 'character'))`

Comment: Would that not make them all character? I want A/B to remain numeric.  I'd think I can do c("numeric", "numeric", "character", "character") but the problem is in some of the data-frames, I may have 1000 columns.  What then?

Comment: @akrun's approach works for me as advertised. What have you tried that it fails you? If you want an automatic way, you are 'doomed' to specify `colClasses` You can read in values line by line and process the output there.

Comment: I guess one approach would be to load `library(bit64)` and then read with `fread` from `library(data.table)`, the column will be read as `integer64`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `colClasses` argument of `read.csv` accepts a named list if you wish to only designate the class of certain columns.

```
txt <- "A,B,C,D
12,34,Yo,67
28,34,Hi,99"

DF <- read.csv(textConnection(txt),
         colClasses = list(D = "character"))

sapply(DF, class)
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much.